# CSS3 - Progress bar design

Tags: css

I'm trying to give a nice style to the progress bars on my website (they're all using jQuery UI).
I'd like it to look something like this : (there's a nice bevel effect and a nice progress indicator below)

[image: Progress bar]

I've tried to play a little with CSS3 to get something like this but I just can't find a good way to do it and what I tried is not really beautiful or even looking like the picture above...

Here's my try : http://jsfiddle.net/xw6zL/2/ ...

Any idea ?

Comment: Did You finish this? I would like to get same effect. Progress bar is OK, but I''m trying to add percent label similar as in Your design. Did You add that to Your site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think that’s quite close: http://jsfiddle.net/xw6zL/4/

fiddle with it :)

---

the effect is achieved by adding two hard box-shadows below the upper and lower border of each element. look at its systax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: Nice, I think what I was missing was the `box-shadow` right ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to some with a little more depth like your example:
http://www.red-team-design.com/stylish-css3-progress-bars
http://lab.galengidman.com/progress-bars/
http://sevenspark.com/free-stuff/css3-progress-bars

I think these are all pretty darn nice CSS3 bars. Each of these have tutorials and source code to help.

Comment: I love the last one, they're really nice.